# Update Field with Special Character ' (single quote)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am workign with SQL Server 2008 and have to update one field (FIELD_NAM) which contains values of this format:

- First value in the field: 'abc', 'efg', 'xyz'
- Second value in the field: 'aaaaa', 'bbbb', 'vvvvvv'

I tried with the following statement:

```
UPDATE Table
SET FIELD = 'ttttt', 'kkkk', 'mmmmmm'
WHERE ID = 1
```

(only one row and one field/column has to be updated)
The error I got is

> Incorrect syntax near 'ttttt'

Comment: Single quotes are a delimiter in sql server.

Answer (score 2):

```
update "table"
   set field = '''ttttt'', ''kkkk'', ''mmmmmm'''
where id = 1
;
```

Comment: Update is functioning. However, I am getting this result: "ttttt", "kkkk", "mmmmmm", which is not what I need. The elements should be inside singel quotes, such as: 'ttttt', 'kkkk', 'mmmmmm'

Comment: this is the correct answer - First I made a mistake by typing double qouotes. Every quote in the answer is a SINGLE QUOUTE - than is functioning

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Table
SET FIELD = 'ttttt\', \'kkkk\', \'mmmmmm'
WHERE ID = 1
```

OR

```
UPDATE Table
SET FIELD = 'ttttt'', ''kkkk'', ''mmmmmm'
WHERE ID = 1
```

Comment: FILED is this way defined: [FIELD] [text] NULL
The statement is

Comment: UPDATE Table
  SET FIELD = '348661130\',\'348698860\',\'348709784\''
  WHERE ID = 1